# \usepackage{endfloat} problem

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

im having problems including an appendix. Here is the line that is causing problems. The problems appers only when i use the package "endfloat"

```
\begin{appendix}

\include{Appendix/ApA}

\end{appendix}
```

And here is the error log

```
Runaway argument?

! File ended while scanning use of \efloat@xfloat.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.171 \include{Appendix/ApA}
                             
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your fil
```

Thank you

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is. What is in `Appendix/Apa`?

Comment: If this error does not occur when not using the `endfloat` package my guess would be that a `figure` or `table` environment is not ending as it should be when using the `endfloat` package. See also section 12.1 "Literal strings" in the `endfloat` package documentation.